# Why I can only get the same result in scrapy when scrapying finished?

Tags: scrapy

The crawler just return the last value of target url's element.
But I suppose to get a list of each element's value and pop them in to the items.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy_practice.items import ScrapyPracticeItem


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dmoz'
    allowed_domains = ['www.dmoz.org']

    start_urls = (
        'http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/',
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        bs = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml')

        sp_item = ScrapyPracticeItem()

        items = []

        for item in bs.find_all(class_='title-and-desc'):
             sp_item['name'] = item.a.div.string
             sp_item['url'] = item.a['href']
             items.append(sp_item)

        print(items)
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but is there any reason you are using beautifulsoup with lxml? Scrapy already has it's own selectors that are using lxml, and response is already this selector so you can replace first 7 lines of parse method with: `for item in response.xpath("//*[@class='title-and-desc']"):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create one item and keep overriding it's fields.

```
def parse(self, response):
#<...>
sp_item = ScrapyPracticeItem()  # <- this is the culprit
items = []
for item in bs.find_all(class_='title-and-desc'):
    # you want to create item object for every item you find
    sp_item = ScrapyPracticeItem()  # <- it should be here
    sp_item['name'] = item.a.div.string
    sp_item['url'] = item.a['href']
    items.append(sp_item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just start scrapy last week and still not familiar with OOP.